# convert csv to dict with specific columns and remove repetitive values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input csv looks something like this:

```
Flower;Price;Customer;Color
Rose;20;Sam;Red, Yellow, Pink, Red
Orchids;50;Jim;White, Purple, White
Tulips;15;Genny;Red, White, Yellow, Yellow
```

first, i want to discard Price and Customer column and only consider Flower and Color.
For that, i am doing

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['Flower','Color'], sep=';')
```

Now, I want to remove duplicate values from "Color" column and keep them in sorted form. (Sorted set)

Things i have tried but did not worked:

data.set_index("Name").T.to_dict('sorted(set)')

data.unique().agg(set).to_dict()

I am expecting output like

```
{
"Rose": [Pink, Red, Yellow],
"Orchids":[Purple, White],
"Tulips":[Red, White, Yellow]
}
```

Please let me know what i am missing.
Thanks for help in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
out = {key: sorted(set(colors.split(', '))) for key, colors in data.values}
```

out:

```
{'Rose': ['Pink', 'Red', 'Yellow'],
 'Orchids': ['Purple', 'White'],
 'Tulips': ['Red', 'White', 'Yellow']}
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

txt = '''Flower;Price;Customer;Color
Rose;20;Sam;Red, Yellow, Pink, Red
Orchids;50;Jim;White, Purple, White
Tulips;15;Genny;Red, White, Yellow, Yellow'''

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), usecols=['Flower','Color'], sep=';')
```

data

```
    Flower  Color
0   Rose    Red, Yellow, Pink, Red
1   Orchids White, Purple, White
2   Tulips  Red, White, Yellow, Yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use pandas for this since you don't care about a DataFrame.

Just use the standard library with `csv`:

```
import csv
import re

out = {row['Flower']: sorted(set(re.split(', *', row['Color'].strip())))
       for row in csv.DictReader(filename, delimiter=';')}
```

Output:

```
{'Rose': ['Pink', 'Red', 'Yellow'],
 'Orchids': ['Purple', 'White'],
 'Tulips': ['Red', 'White', 'Yellow']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use core python like below:

```
lines = """Flower;Price;Customer;Color
Rose;20;Sam;Red, Yellow, Pink, Red
Orchids;50;Jim;White, Purple, White
Tulips;15;Genny;Red, White, Yellow, Yellow"""

result = {}
for line in lines.split('\n')[1:]:
    parts = line.split(';')
    result[parts[0]] = list(set(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(';')[-1].split(',')))))
```

Result:

```
{
    "Rose": [
        "Red",
        "Yellow",
        "Pink"
    ],
    "Orchids": [
        "White",
        "Purple"
    ],
    "Tulips": [
        "Red",
        "Yellow",
        "White"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should Do the Trick

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=['Flower','Color'], sep=';')

flower_colors = {flower: list(set(item.strip() for item in list(data[data['Flower'] == flower]['Color'])[0].split(','))) for flower in data['Flower']}
print(flower_colors)
```